# add app settings in ConfigurationManager without saving

Tags: c#, .net, configurationmanager

I am picking my application settings from database.
I want to add these setting to my application at runtime. I do not want to use config file because i do not want that anyone can see my settings.

if i use : 
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

and then set the settings. the problem is that i have to save and refresh the settings which saves the configuration physically in file.

If i directly use ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["key"] it also requires to have key(i put them without value) in app settings in advance.

I just want to maintain my global settings in memory so that user or anyone can't see settings. What is the solution ?

Comment: Why are you using ConfigurationManager if you just want to maintain an in-memory list of settings. Why not use a Dictionary or Hashtable instead?

Comment: These settings are per user or per application? Have you tried using a singleton to keep the information, if possible?

Comment: @Pete i have enum of settings in a class. enum settings { a, b, c}. how can i maintain it in memory.

Comment: @user1750877 Okay, well then create a singleton class as marcoaoteixeira suggested... But it just seems you're trying ot use the wrong tool for the job. You can create a custom settings container simply enough.

Comment: @Pete thanx for you suggestions. so you are saying i should create a static Property class with static properties and use it everywhere

Comment: Well, a Singleton: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx